# Magento 1.9 removing back slashes while saving a file path to DB

Tags: magento-1.9, database, forms, jquery

Here is the query in controller to save an uploaded file path from a custom directory to database custom table but it is not including the actual page query removed the slashes and the add plain string in to database table

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
        $prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
        $table = 'magesf_ordercustom';
        $query = "insert into ".$prefix.$table." "
             . "(order_id,image_url,image_comments,customer_id) values "
             . "('$orderid', '$paths', '$attach_comments','$order_cus_id')";

        $binds = array(
          'order_id'    => $orderid,
          'image_url'   => $paths,
          'image_comments' => $attach_comments,
          'customer_id' => $order_cus_id,

        );

        $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
```

Actual path should be like this:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/magento_dev/media/customer_documents/error.png
```

But it is saving as:

```
C:xampphtdocsmagento_devmediacustomer_documentserror.png
```

What is the issue with query is there any default behaviour of Magento?

Please guide.